# Access VB Nested If Then Else

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba

I am working in Access and having trouble with my if statement. It never gets to the update, and it always to the last Else.  It really doesn't work if I try to clear the fields for the next entry.  Can someone offer some insight? Thanks.

```
'Check to see they entered a skill rating - this works well
If IsNull(Me.Skill_Combo.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter skill rating.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
ElseIf IsNull(Me.Attitude_Combo.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter an attitude rating.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
ElseIf IsNull(Me.Listens_Combo.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter an Listens/Follows Direction rating.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
ElseIf IsNull(Me.Punctual_Combo.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter an Punctual rating.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
'Check to see if the rating is 0 or 1, and if so require them to leave a comment
ElseIf (Me.Skill_Combo.Value < 2 Or Attitude_Combo.Value < 2 Or Listens_Combo.Value < 2 Or Punctual_Combo.Value < 2) Then
    If IsNull(Comment_Box.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a comment for ratings lower than 2.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"  'It gets here like it should, but only the first time
    Else  'It never gets here!
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "UpdateEmployee", acViewNormal, acEdit
        MsgBox "Successfully Updated" & ".", vbOKOnly, "Success"
        'Clear values to select next employee
'                Me.Skill_Combo.Value = ""
'                Me.Attitude_Combo.Value = ""
'                Me.Listens_Combo.Value = ""
'                Me.Punctual_Combo.Value = ""
'                Me.Comment_Box.Value = ""
    End If
Else
        MsgBox "You shouldn't be getting this message box, but it always 

ends up here"
```

I have also tried this and it works better, but still does not work..

```
'Check to see if the rating is low, and if so require a comment
ElseIf (Me.Skill_Combo.Value < 2 Or Attitude_Combo.Value < 2 Or Listens_Combo.Value < 2 Or Punctual_Combo.Value < 2) And IsNull(Comment_Box.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a comment for ratings lower than 2.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
ElseIf (Me.Skill_Combo.Value >= 2 Or Attitude_Combo.Value >= 2 Or Listens_Combo.Value >= 2 Or Punctual_Combo.Value >= 2) And Not IsNull(Comment_Box.Value) Then
```

Comment: VB.NET <> VBA/Access-VBA

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your combos don't hold Null values.

Prepend and/or Insert debug lines to find out, like:

```
Debug.Print Me!Skill_Combo.Name, Me!Skill_Combo.Value
```

Or test for empty strings rather than Null:

```
If Nz(Me!Skill_Combo.Value) = "" Then
```

Comment: Thank you.  Putting an empty string doesn't work. I think this whole thing is messed up and I'm going to have to start from scratch.  I'm just not understanding why it's not working, and am getting frustrated.  It seems like it should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working.  Thanks for leading me in the right direction!

```
'Check to see they entered a skill rating
If (Me.Skill_Combo.Value = "") Or IsNull(Me.Skill_Combo.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter skill rating.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
ElseIf (Me.Attitude_Combo.Value = "") Or IsNull(Me.Attitude_Combo.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter an attitude rating.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
ElseIf (Me.Listens_Combo.Value = "") Or IsNull(Me.Listens_Combo.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter an Listens/Follows Direction rating.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
ElseIf (Me.Punctual_Combo.Value = "") Or IsNull(Me.Punctual_Combo.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter an Punctual rating.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"

'Check to see if the rating is low, and if so require a comment
ElseIf (Me.Skill_Combo.Value < 2 Or Attitude_Combo.Value < 2 Or Listens_Combo.Value < 2 Or Punctual_Combo.Value < 2) And ((IsNull(Me.Comment_Box.Value)) Or (Me.Comment_Box.Value = "")) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a comment for ratings lower than 2.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
        DoCmd.Requery "EmpList"
  Else
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "UpdateEmployee", acViewNormal, acEdit
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        MsgBox "Successfully Updated" & ".", vbOKOnly, "Success"

        Me.Skill_Combo.Value = ""
        Me.Attitude_Combo.Value = ""
        Me.Listens_Combo.Value = ""
        Me.Punctual_Combo.Value = ""
        Me.Comment_Box.Value = ""
        DoCmd.Requery "EmpList"


End If
End Sub
```

Comment: OK. Please note that `(Me.Skill_Combo.Value = "") Or IsNull(Me.Skill_Combo.Value)` essentially is equal to `Nz(Me.Skill_Combo.Value) = ""`.

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate your help.